# bookshelf.js timestamps not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm experimenting with bookshelf.js right now, and I created a sample table using the following knex migration:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable( "users", function( table ) {
        table.increments();
        table.timestamps();
        table.string( "email" );
    } );
};
```

I then defined a bookshelf.js model:

```
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend( {
    tableName: "users"
} );
```

and tried to save it:

```
var u = new User( { email: "john.doe@example.com" } );
u.save();
```

Everything seems to work, and when I look at the database, the new user really was saved, however the timestamp-columns are `NULL`. Also calling `u.timestamp()` before calling `u.save()` doesn't seem to have any effect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ha, I finally got it!

You have to tell the model to use timestamps like this:

```
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend( {
    tableName: "users",
    hasTimestamps: true
} );
```

Comment: after adding 'hasTimestamps: true' , updated_at works fine, but it doesn't respond back updatedData. It only updated in database

Answer (score 0):

example in typescript

```
import bookshelf from '../config/bookshelf';

class User extends bookshelf.Model<User> {
  get tableName(): string {
    return 'users';
  }
  get hasTimestamps(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

export default User;
```